# Compressing uncompressed video is hit or miss

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am using AviManager I have a list of images in a Bitmap list, which I am creating an uncompressed stream from like so:

```
        // create the file
        WaveFileReader wf = new WaveFileReader(VideoLocation);
        AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(VideoLocation, false);

        // Get the time of the audio and divide by images
        double time = wf.TotalTime.TotalSeconds;
        var co = (int)Math.Ceiling(time) * 2;
        var mimtime = co / urls.Count;

        //add a new video stream and one frame to the new file
        Images[0].RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
        VideoStream aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 2, Images[0]);

        for (var i = 0; i < Images.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0) // fix flipped looping bug for first image
            {
                Images[i].RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
            }
            int n = 0;
            while (n < mimtime)
            {
                aviStream.AddFrame(Images[i]);
                n++;
            }
            n = 0;
        }
```

This generates an AVI file fine, now when I go to compress that video and add an audio like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Compress the video, and add the audio stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task CompressVideo()
    {
        // Compressing Video
        StatusTextChanged?.Invoke(this, $"Compressing video");

        // Compress
        AviManager avManager = new AviManager(VideoLocation, true);
        VideoStream avStream = avManager.GetVideoStream();

        VideoStream newStream;
        AviManager newManager = avStream.DecompressToNewFile(CompressedVideo, true, out newStream);

        avManager.Close();
        newManager.Close();

        // Adding audio to video
        StatusTextChanged?.Invoke(this, $"Adding audio to video");

        // Add the audio
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
        if (CompressedVideo != null && ArticleAudio != null)
        {
            AviManager audiovideo = new AviManager(CompressedVideo, true);
            audiovideo.AddAudioStream(ArticleAudio, 0);
            audiovideo.Close();
        }
    }
```

it's hit or miss whether it compresses or gets the error;

[image]

Sometimes the video gets up to 3MB, then gets the error, Sometimes it gets to 12MB then gets the error, sometimes it actually compresses the whole video, how can I fix this?

Comment: Since you are getting NRE you should read through standard answer first and provide [MCVE]. In current state of the post does not show what steps you've already taken to resolve the issue.

Comment: There's nothing to try to resolve this, by their documents, the code I am using should work, but it doesn't hence why I am asking here to see if anybody has experienced this